# Emulate document pages in Quill js editor

Tags: javascript, quill

I would like to achieve the effect of the multipage document in Quill editor. What I mean by that is, after text will reach the certain amount of max pixels height (some equivalent of 300dpi)it will create page break/or jump to next page (container editor instance). Something like in Google Docs.

[image]

I wanted to just create another instance of quill and focus into it but that would create another toolbar (single toolbar for multiple editors is not supported yet, but there is pr for that)

For now, I am just creating a divider which is a `div` element with the same color as the background behind the white page.

Does anyone know some nice and clean solution for that or have any ideas how I could solve it?

Comment: Hello! I have the same question? Did you find some solutions yet?

Comment: I just do not understand the advantages of spawning a Quill editor per page. A divider Block element seems a good solution to me, since all your document (all the pages) are within the same Quill.getContents(); The problem would be to programatically change the block position depending on the contents. You could use a Clipboard method that on each character added looks if it needs to be placed differently?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to listening on the editor's height to trigger adding another, There are many approach within Quill's API or outside with your own vanilla. Not a problem.

To the multiple Editors sharing a single Toolbar,

Here is a thread from, still an **Open**, issue on QuillJS:

[Consider allowing multiple editors on the same page & to use the same toolbar. #633](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/633)

One neat solution is from [this](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/633#issuecomment-440623398) comment by [Pawel Glowacki](https://github.com/PawelGlow)

> **3. Initialize a Quill editor inside the active box only and destroy the previous editor + one toolbar This is the solution I am using
>   today and it results in the best performance and a some what clean
>   solution. When the active box changes, I get the Quill instance
>   content, remove the previous Quill events + instance, and I update the
>   DOM as the HTML created by the editor is not removed automatically.**
>
> I am using this quill delta to html addon
>
> ```
> if (window.editor) {
>     //Get the content
>     var content = '';
>     if (window.editor.getLength() > 1) {
>         var delta = window.editor.getContents(); //store globally
>         var converter = new QuillDeltaToHtmlConverter(delta.ops, {});
>         var html = converter.convert();
>         if (typeof html !== "undefined" && html !== null) {
>             content = html;
>         }
>     }
>
>     //remove any [on events](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#events) you attached to the Quill instance 
>
>     //remove Quill instance
>     window.editor = undefined;
>
>     // clean DOM and set content
>     document.getElementById('previousBoxId').classList.remove('ql-container');
>     document.getElementById('previousBoxId').innerHTML = content;
> }
>
> //create new quill instance
> window.editor = new Quill(...)
>
> //set the editor contents ("//store globally" comment above)
> if (editorContent) {
>     window.editor.setContents(editorContent)
> }
> ```
>
> window.editor.focus(); //initialize any [on
>   events](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#events) if you want The downside
>   of Quill not managing multiple instances of the editor with a single
>   toolbar is not a big problem, but it does require you to do the
>   research/testing + add the logic yourself, which can be a hassle.
>
> I hope someone finds this useful.
>
> If you need to keep track of multiple Quill instances at once, create
>   a JavaScript object and store them under some key.
>
> ```
> window.editors = {
>    editor1: Quill_instance,
>    editor2: Quill_instance,
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> I was also not able to find a better solution in the Quill docs but I
>   have a very large app which handles 50+ toolbars and destroying the
>   toolbar then creating a new one each time I create a new Quill
>   instance has not caused any issues.

Comment: While this would work for multiple editors as mentioned in the comment, it is not good enough for implementing pages. Since pages are laid one below the other, contents can overflow from one to other, or users can select content all of the pages for formatting

Comment: That's another problem to solve after successfully handling multiple editors. You can always loop through your collection of editors (e.g. `window.editors` above) and apply formatting. If you want to select all text from all pages, you'll probably gonna use Ctrl+A, we can programmatically handle that also.

Comment: In this case, how would you handle overflowing content from one page to other?

Comment: Haven't made a solid solution to passing of the substrings from one editor to another. Ideally we could listen to the inputing and i guess crosscheck the length of the string in the active editor with its max. Very hard part for the full feature. sheeezz  

Comment: I wish. The editor toolbar would have features for font size or inserting an image which would totally mess up the sub string thing

Comment: Yeah, I realized too, there's a lot to handle. Initially I was thinking of getting the total height of all the `p`'s in the editor and compare it to the desired max height of editor. That way we can also include adding the heights of inserted images hoping there's no inline images. If there are, i'm sure we can still add logic to checking the classes.